# how to write javascript regular expression that accept number range between 8 to 15 integer with decimal number also?

Tags: javascript

I want to make the javascript regular expression that match only the numbers between 8 to 15 (not negative value). The regular expression should also accept decimal point, like 8.7 or 9.5 and so on till 15.

```
/^0*([89]|1[0-5])$/
```

I have tried the above regular expression but it doesn't allow decimal point.
Can anyone help me to make the javascript regular expression?

Comment: *why* do you want to do this with regex? It's possible but it's definitely the wrong tool for the job. It basically involves listing each possible permutation. Whereas if you just treat this as a number, you can do something like `num >= 8 && num <= 15`

Comment: @VLAZ: you're assuming that their input is a number, which might or might not be the case. For example, it can be some kind of code, so that `11.5` is valid, but `11.534982347923` is not. `8 < n < 15` won't work here.

Comment: OP: simply add `(\. that thing)?` before the end `$`

Comment: @georg it's possible but I've seen enough times regex employed when it shouldn't be. Hence the question - why regex.

Comment: @JamesThorpe validation [is still possible without regex or code](https://jsbin.com/xoqakaruwe/edit?html,output). And most validation libraries I've seen allow you to do something equivalent to this. So, *again* why is regex needed instead of alternatives?

Comment: I have make the regular expression the solve the above  problem. /^0*([89]|1[0-5]\d*)\.\d$/

Comment: Sorry, but your expression is not quite right, at least according to your definition, as it allows a number >15 (e.g. "15.5" works) but also disallows anything without a decimal point ("9" fails).  This strengthens the point from @VLAZ - interpretation of this kind is not really what a regex is designed for.  Rather a better pattern is to recongize a number, parse it, then test the range as a number.  To fix your regex you would need to make the decimal optional, and also adding a specific exception for "15" and "15.0" but not "15.x" where x>0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
/^0*(?:[89]|1[0-5])(?:\.\d)?$/
```

But this will allow `15.99999999`, as the integer part (`15`) is allowed. To restrict it, you have to use a different case for it, like:

```
/^0*(?:(?:[89]|1[0-4])(?:\.\d)?|15(?:\.0+)?)$/
```

[Inspect on *regex101.com*](https://regex101.com/r/NOfK4Q/4)

But I have to mention that validating numbers using regular expressions is not a too good idea.

The following is more performant and much more semantical:

```
const number= +input
if (8<=number && number<=15){
  //Valid number
}
```